# Pointwise convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Given $a_j$ non negative, and

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_j}{j} < \infty$$

how do I show that

$$f_n = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \mathbb{1}_j}{n} \to 0 $$ pointwise on $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2):

At every $k \in \Bbb{N}$ you have (for $n \ge k$)
$$f_n(k) = \frac{a_k}{n} \to 0$$
hence your sequence of functions converges pointwise to $0$.

Comment: oh shoot lol, talk about a brain fart... i was trying to prove something about limsup of the a_j...